# JavaScript and images files are not recognized

Tags: images, javascript

It might be the simplest question but I can't find why my JavaScript files and images are not recognized by WordPress. I put all my JS files and images in my theme's folder, so I created a folder "word" inside "theme", with all the content and then I added my files. But the website doesn't recognize the path to the JavaScript or the images. Could you please tell me what i'm doing wrong?

I used it like that in the header page :

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give the full path to your theme files. To get the URL of your theme, use the WordPress function `bloginfo( 'template_directory' );` so at a minimum you would need:

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) ?>/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However, scripts / styles should really be "enqueued" using `wp_enqueue_script();` (see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

I would recommend taking a look at some other themes to see how they include thetheme files like this. Also the Codex page on Theme Development is a good place to start: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development